# Contains Method doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, methods, compare

Using the code below, I want to compare the `UserType`, if it is "Student" I want to redirect to student profile, etc.

But it always gets to the last `else` statement and Writes an Error.

The `returnQuery` method works well because it returns the value "Student".

```
String emailID = Session["New"].ToString();
string usertype = returnQuery(
    "select userType from Registration where email = '" + lblEmail.Text + "'");

if (usertype.Contains("Student"))
{         
    Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx?email=" + emailID.ToString());
}
else if (usertype.Contains("Company"))
{ 
    Response.Redirect("CompanyProfile.aspx?email=" + emailID.ToString());
}
else if(usertype.Contains("Admin"))
{
    Response.Redirect("AdminProfile.aspx?email=" + emailID.ToString());
}
else
    Response.Write("Error");
```

Comment: HI, What is the value of `usertype` for a specific email? You said that returnQuery method works well. Please let us know what is this method returns for saying so. Thanks

Comment: Debug the value of  `usertype`. Maybe it really doesn't have the value you're checking for.

Comment: FYI: See [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: the method returns Student to a Label because the userType for the profile is Student.

Comment: `else Response.Write(usertype);`

Comment: Ok I came to a weird conclusion that Student is returned in the Page_load method but not Button1_Click I can post the entire code here

Answer (score 0):

If `usertype="Student"` you can use `usertype.Equals("Student");` to determine the variable.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the method.

Comment: I tried both of them no luck, the problem is weird when this code is in Page_load it works but when it's in the method of a button click it doesnt work....

Comment: @KamilRipperPantlinowski That's a sign your value doesn't equal what you think it does. Try using your IDE's debugger to see what the values are.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are dealing with a Page Lifecycle issue. lblEmail.Text is likely not what you expect it to be during Postback Event Handling time of the button click.

Verify that you are not modifying the contents of lblEmail.Text at any point before the button click event is processed, and verify the value of lblEmail.Text at the time the click event is processed.

For more information about Page Lifecycle, see this MSDN article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx